# Posting object AJAX to MVC controller results in all properties being null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to post an object from jquery to MVC controller.  The object is passed successfully but all the properties are null (or false for bools).

fwiw, if I JSON.stringify myObect then it does not pass at all, theObect in the controller is null.

I am using MVC4, .net 4.5, jQuery 1.9.1

Any help appreciate.

**jQuery function**

```
var myObject =
{
    Property1: true,
    Proerty2: true
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/myController/StartProcess/',
    data: { theObject: myObject }
});
```

**Controller**

```
private async void StartProcess(myObject theObject)
{
     // theObect can be seen successfully but property1 and property2 are false
     // if I change them to strings they are null
     ...
}
```

**Class**

```
public class myObject
{
    public bool Property1 { get; set; }
    public bool Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The solution was:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/myController/StartProcess/',
    data:  myObject
});
```

If anyone can shed some light as to why this works and nothing else does it would be greatly appreciated.  It is not a great solution because I have to put all my parameters in myObject, I cannot pass any additional parameters using this technique.  also curious as to why all the info I find online, including official tutorials, say to use data: JSON.Strinify(myObect) but for me this causes all the properties of myObject to be null (or false).

Thanks to Roar all the same, at least I can move past this.

Comment: Case-sensitivity will get you every time.

Comment: I have no idea why this needs to be like this, but thanks, I was fighting with JSON stringnify and it never worked, all the properties of the object were null on the server side.

But, by just using the object without modification as the parameters, it works. Thanks for posting your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Get this [JSON library](http://www.json.org/js.html) and `stringify()` the `object` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/myController/StartProcess/',
    data: JSON.stringify(myObject)
});
```

Comment: As mentioned, this makes the whole object null in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/myController/StartProcess/',
    data: myObject
});
```

Comment: Same result, myObject is accessible in the controller but properties are all false.

Comment: Sorry, that did work, but only if it is the only parameter.  I simplified my post and actually have additional parameters being passed. How can I do data: myObject along with passing other parameters?

Comment: I have marked this as the answer, although I am unclear as to why this works when every tutorial I read says to use JSON.Stringify.  It's also means I cannot send any other parameters with it.  Any input as to what is going on here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried to POST your object to an API controller, it would probably work. I had some trouble with this myself. If you're using jQuery, you need to specify that you're sending JSON so the MVC controller will correctly interpret the data.

You could try this:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: { theObject: myObject },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/myController/StartProcess/'
});
```

Comment: specifying contentType: 'application/json' gives the same result.  All properties are null in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what can also make all properties null :

```
public ActionResult GetPaymentView(CardModel Card)
{
}
```

If the view is a collection of a model, when you pass a serialized form of one element in the collection to ajax call, the controller expects the same name instance as the class name.  I assume that this is the same way without collection but never tried.  In this code example we serialize one element of the collection

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Shipments/GetPaymentView',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#' + ID).serialize(),
    success: { onSuccess(); },
    error: { onError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }
});
```

The reason why this happens is because the view model is a collection of the CardModel and the serialization is adding **CardModel** before each properties like this : CardModel.ID=foo&CardModel.bar The model binder takes it as granted and tries to match the instance sent with the property of the controller which it can't and instantiate a new instance for you hence all properties are nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" to your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally figured it out.  Here is a full and proper solution showing how to pass additional parameters along with the object:

**jQuery:**

```
var myString= "my paramter";
var myObject =
{
     Property1: true,
     Property2: true
};

var DTO = { param1: myString, param2: myObject };

$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myController/StartProcess',
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO)
});
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost] // notice this additional attribute!
private async void StartProcess(string param1, myObject param2)
{
     // param2 parameters are all true! param1 shows correctly too.
     ...
}
```

**Class**

```
public class myObject
{
    public bool Property1 { get; set; }
    public bool Property2 { get; set; }
}
```